# Signing an Access file without an extension .accdb or .accde does not work

Tags: vba, ms-access, code-signing

For some time now it has been possible again to sign Access VBA code with the current Access 365 version.

This also works as long as the extension of the Access file ends in .accdb or .accde. If this is not the case, as is the case with us, signing will no longer work. No error is thrown, the file simply remains unsigned. Mind you, the same file with extension .accdb works.  Anyone have an idea?

First sign then rename, the certificate is removed again.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  Signing no longer works on mdb files?  mdb went out when Access 2007 came out, so could be that the extension is coming on for 20 years out of date?

Comment: So far we have been using a completely different extension, e.g. .BLA. That was never a problem until the customer requested the signature. The question is, is it possible to sign a file with an ending other than .accdb or .accdb in a detour?

Comment: *a completely different extension, e.g. .BLA* - that's a rather odd thing to do. Obfuscating file types by using a random extension is something that I would associate with malware. So IMHO it is reasonable to not allowing this to be signed.